# Decentralized application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, solidity, web3js

I made a login page with metamask for my Dapp, but now I need to link my login button to the profile page which will have student details like name, phonenumber, certificates (pdf) etc. where these data must be stored in a smart contract (solidity). I've also written the smart contract code. But the problem is I have no idea how to fetch the code in frontend written in typescript. Please give me a idea to code which does the job. I'll link my login.tsx file and solidity code.

Login.tsx:

```
import './Login.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

import { Auth } from '../types';

interface Props {
    onLoggedIn: (auth: Auth) => void;
}

let web3: Web3 | undefined = undefined; // Will hold the web3 instance

export const Login = ({ onLoggedIn }: Props): JSX.Element => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); // Loading button state

    const handleAuthenticate = ({
        publicAddress,
        signature,
    }: {
        publicAddress: string;
        signature: string;
    }) =>
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/auth`, {
            body: JSON.stringify({ publicAddress, signature }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
        }).then((response) => response.json());

    const handleSignMessage = async ({
        publicAddress,
        nonce,
    }: {
        publicAddress: string;
        nonce: string;
    }) => {
        try {
            const signature = await web3!.eth.personal.sign(
                `I am signing my one-time nonce: ${nonce}`,
                publicAddress,
                '' // MetaMask will ignore the password argument here
            );

            return { publicAddress, signature };
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(
                'You need to sign the message to be able to log in.'
            );
        }
    };

    const handleSignup = (publicAddress: string) =>
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/users`, {
            body: JSON.stringify({ publicAddress }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
        }).then((response) => response.json());

    const handleClick = async () => {
        // Check if MetaMask is installed
        if (!(window as any).ethereum) {
            window.alert('Please install MetaMask first.');
            return;
        }

        if (!web3) {
            try {
                // Request account access if needed
                await (window as any).ethereum.enable();

                // We don't know window.web3 version, so we use our own instance of Web3
                // with the injected provider given by MetaMask
                web3 = new Web3((window as any).ethereum);
            } catch (error) {
                window.alert('You need to allow MetaMask.');
                return;
            }
        }

        const coinbase = await web3.eth.getCoinbase();
        if (!coinbase) {
            window.alert('Please activate MetaMask first.');
            return;
        }

        const publicAddress = coinbase.toLowerCase();
        setLoading(true);

        // Look if user with current publicAddress is already present on backend
        fetch(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/users?publicAddress=${publicAddress}`
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            // If yes, retrieve it. If no, create it.
            .then((users) =>
                users.length ? users[0] : handleSignup(publicAddress)
            )
            // Popup MetaMask confirmation modal to sign message
            .then(handleSignMessage)
            // Send signature to backend on the /auth route
            .then(handleAuthenticate)
            // Pass accessToken back to parent component (to save it in localStorage)
            .then(onLoggedIn)
            .catch((err) => {
                window.alert(err);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Please Signup with MetaMask and Login</p>
            <button className="Login-button Login-mm" onClick={handleClick}>
                {loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Login with MetaMask'}
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In the handleClick function I need to link my profile.tsx page,which is connected to solidity code.

Please someone help me to write the code for profile.tsx

Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract register{
    string name;
    string dept;
    uint phonenumber;
    string addresshome;
    string emailid;
    uint aadhar;
    string ipfshash1;
    string ipfshash2;
    string ipfshash3;
    string ipfshash4;
    constructor() public {
        phonenumber=0;
        aadhar=0;
        
    }
    
    function getname(string memory _name) public pure returns(string memory){
        return _name;
    }
    
    function getdept(string memory _dept) public pure returns(string memory){
        return _dept;
    }
    
    function getphonenumber(uint _phonenumber) public pure returns(uint){
        return _phonenumber;
    }
    
    function getaddresshome(string memory _addresshome) public pure returns(string memory){
        return _addresshome;
    }
    
    function getemailid(string memory _emailid) public pure returns(string memory){
        return _emailid;
    }
    
    function getaadhar(uint _aadhar) public pure returns(uint){
        return _aadhar;
    }
    
    function sendhash1(string memory a) public {
        ipfshash1=a;
    }
     function gethash1() public view returns(string memory a) {
        return ipfshash1;
    }
    
    function sendhash2(string memory b) public {
        ipfshash2=b;
    }
     function gethash2() public view returns(string memory b) {
        return ipfshash2;
    }
    
    function sendhash3(string memory c) public {
        ipfshash3=c;
    }
     function gethash3() public view returns(string memory c) {
        return ipfshash3;
    }
    
    function sendhash4(string memory d) public {
        ipfshash4=d;
    }
     function gethash4() public view returns(string memory d) {
        return ipfshash4;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Stack Overflow is not a freelance coding site. The people who answer questions here are experts who volunteer their time to answer practical programming problems, not whole tasks they would normally get paid for. Please be respectful of their time. Do some research and make an attempt to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: No offence frnd! I don't know how to fetch it, so I asked